# Updating list on two different

Tags: sub-site

I have a parent site and a sub-site. The sub-site has an invoicing form that uses a customer list. Now behind this list is a workflow that allows the user to type in a customer name. I am using a combo box so if they are a existing customer their name will be available in the combo box if it is a new customer that does not already exist the workflow will add their name to the customer list. The issue is that the customer list is needed in both sites and I need a way to update the customer list when a new customer is added to the customer list on the subsite.

Comment: Found a work around for this. Instead of using a workflow rather create a flow using Microsoft flow as it has the ability for you to be able to read and write between list living in different sites.